# Option field on change Ajax post/get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have select tag and option fields (example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D34g6/)). 
I want when user clicks on option, that some content (based on value) appear in collapse (like in `View more` button).
If it possible, some Ajax get request will be good (i must send a option value), and i will provide data in backend. 
Iam very week on Ajax, and i did not even know how to begin.

Thanx

```
<select id="id_employees" name="employees">
<option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
<option value="4">Some text</option>
<option value="5">Some text1</option>
<option value="6">Some text2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
$('#id_employees').change(function(e) {
    // e.target.value contains the selected value
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data-source.php',        
        success: function(data) {
            $('#id-of-container').append(data);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for that. I made it now, but how to get collapse effect, like if i clicked a button on exmaple?